# Wrong output from a python application running in linux terminal which is running correctly on python IDE

Tags: python, linux, terminal, ide, serial-port

I have a python application that run perfectly on python IDE. It makes serial communication with an external device.

```
import serial, string
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 38400, timeout=10.0)
serial.PARITY_NONE
serial.EIGHTBITS
serial.STOPBITS_ONE


#Set Rotor size

port.write(bytes([53, 4, 36, 0, 83]))
print("Set Rotor size")
data = port.read(20)
data1= list(data)
print(data1)
```

I get the following correct output

> > > ```
> > > Set Rotor size
> > > [53, 1, 4, 0, 83, 53, 27, 0, 132, 83]
> > > ```

But when I try to run in the linux terminal, I get different output which is wrong.

```
pi@raspberrypi /home/python $ python serialcomm.py
Set Rotor Size
['[', '5', '3', '\xff', ' ', ',', ' ', '8', '3', ']', ',', ' ', '8', '\xff',     ']'                                                                                                             , ',', '\x1b', '\x01', '\x84', ']']
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using python 3 IDE to run thre script. Whereas in the Linux, the default version was python 2.

I could get the correct output using the command line

```
    pi@raspberrypi /home/python $ python3 serialcomm.py
```